# Mirroring folders

Tags: macos

I want to know if there is a way to have mirror
folders with a remote machine. I see some solutions for 
syncing folders with a backup drive, but I am not interested
in that. I want to sync a folder with a remote machine through
ssh. I am on OSX leopard

Ted.

Comment: You get better answer for this question if you post on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the rsync command line utility.  You may even be able to find some good GUI applications that build on rsync.  Although I haven't tested it, [Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/) looks promising.

Comment: Yea I looked for mirroring folders with rsync is good for me.